# Round Robin Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11

Here I have implemented code for Round Robin CPU Scheduling Algorithm. scheduling.h header file is also used in Shortest Job First Scheduling Algorithm and Priority Scheduling Algorithm, so it contains common data members and member functions.

First I have calculated end time in `calcEndTime()` then using formula `turnAroundTime = endTime - arrivalTime` calculated Turnaround time and using `waitingTime = turnAroundTime - burstTime` calculated Waiting time.

Please help me to improve and optimize this code using more C++11 and C++14 features.

scheduling.h

```
#ifndef SCHEDULING_H_
#define SCHEDULING_H_

#include <vector>

class Scheduling
{
    uint currActiveProcessID;
    uint timeCounter = 0;
    double avgWaitingTime;
    double avgTurnAroundTime;

    std::vector<unsigned> arrivalTime;
    //When process start to execute
    std::vector<unsigned> burstTime;
    //process wait to execute after they have arrived
    std::vector<unsigned> waitingTime;
    //total time taken by processes
    std::vector<unsigned> turnAroundTime;
    //time when a process end
    std::vector<unsigned> endTime;

  public:
    Scheduling(unsigned num = 0);
    Scheduling(const Scheduling&)            = delete;
    Scheduling &operator=(const Scheduling&) = delete;
    Scheduling(Scheduling&&)                 = delete;
    Scheduling &operator=(Scheduling&&)      = delete;
    ~Scheduling()                            = default;

    void calcWaitingTime();
    void calcTurnAroundTime();
    void calcEndTime();
    void printInfo();

  private:
    void sortAccordingArrivalTime();
};

#endif
```

roundrobin.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits
#include "scheduling.h"

unsigned timeQuantum = 0;

Scheduling::Scheduling(unsigned num)
{
    unsigned arrivalVal, burstVal;
    currActiveProcessID = 0;
    timeCounter = 0;
    std::cout << "\nEnter time quantum : ";
    std::cin >> timeQuantum;
    arrivalTime.reserve(num);
    burstTime.reserve(num);
    endTime.reserve(num);

    std::cout << "\nEnter arrival time and burst time eg(5 18)\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nProcess" << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> arrivalVal >> burstVal;
        arrivalTime.push_back(arrivalVal);
        burstTime.push_back(burstVal);
    }
}

void Scheduling::sortAccordingArrivalTime()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arrivalTime.size(); i++)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = i+1; j < arrivalTime.size(); j++)
        {
            if (arrivalTime[i] > arrivalTime[j])
            {
                std::swap(arrivalTime[i], arrivalTime[j]);
                std::swap(burstTime[i], burstTime[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Scheduling::calcEndTime()
{
    //If arrival time is not sorted
    //sort burst time according to arrival time
    sortAccordingArrivalTime();

    //copy values of burst time in new vector
    std::vector<unsigned> burstTimeCopy;
    std::copy(burstTime.begin(), burstTime.end(),
              std::back_inserter(burstTimeCopy));

    while (!(std::all_of(burstTimeCopy.begin(), burstTimeCopy.end(),
            [] (unsigned e) { return e == 0; })))
    {
        currActiveProcessID = 0;
        auto it = burstTimeCopy.begin();
        while (it != burstTimeCopy.end())
        {
            if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] > timeQuantum)
            {
                burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] -= timeQuantum;
                timeCounter += timeQuantum;
            }
            else if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] > 0)
            {
                timeCounter += burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID];
                burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] = 0;
                endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
            }
            currActiveProcessID++;
            it++;
        }
    }
}

void Scheduling::calcTurnAroundTime()
{
    double sum = 0.00;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arrivalTime.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned val = endTime[i] - arrivalTime[i];
        turnAroundTime.push_back(val);
        sum += (double)val;
    }
    avgTurnAroundTime = sum / turnAroundTime.size();
}

void Scheduling::calcWaitingTime()
{
    double sum = 0.00;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < burstTime.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned val = turnAroundTime[i] - burstTime[i];
        waitingTime.push_back(val);
        sum += (double)val;
    }
    avgWaitingTime = sum / waitingTime.size();
}

void Scheduling::printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "ProcessID\tArrival Time\tBurst Time\tEnd Time\tWaiting Time";
    std::cout << "\tTurnaround Time\n";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arrivalTime.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << "\t\t" << arrivalTime[i] << "\t\t" << burstTime[i];
        std::cout << "\t\t"<<endTime[i] << "\t\t" << waitingTime[i] <<"\t\t";
        std::cout << turnAroundTime[i] <<'\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Average Waiting Time : " << avgWaitingTime << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average Turn Around Time : " << avgTurnAroundTime << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter number of process: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    Scheduling roundRobin(num);
    roundRobin.calcEndTime();
    roundRobin.calcTurnAroundTime();
    roundRobin.calcWaitingTime();
    roundRobin.printInfo();
}
```

Comment: There's no definition for `uint`. Was this intended to be `unsigned`, or is the definition missing entirely (e.g. by missing an `#include`)?

Comment: First I used `using uint = unsigned int` then I thought it is better to use `unsigned`. I forgot to change that.

Answer (score 3):

Where does the `uint` type come from?

The `currActiveProcessID` member of `Scheduling` can be removed from the class, as it is only used internally to `calcEndTime()`.

`timeQuantum` should be entered in `main` (or a helper function) or passed in on the command line, not as part of the class constructor.  Then pass it into the class as a parameter to the constructor, and store it within the class.

All of your accesses to `endTime` result in Undefined Behavior.  You `reserve()` some space in the vector, but never actually resize the vector.  This leaves the vector with a `size()` of 0.

If you use a struct to hold your various time vectors, then your sort can easily be a simple call to `std::sort` (which will be faster than the sort you wrote).  Changing from a struct-of-vectors to a vector-of-structs approach would also simplify other parts of your code (`calcTurnAroundTime`, `calcWaitingTime`), since you wouldn't need to index into multiple arrays.  Just user iterators.  If you leave them as separate vectors, you copy of `burstTime` can be `auto burstTimeCopy = burstTime;` without using `std::copy` (although `burstTimeCopy` can be eliminated; see below).

The while loop in `calcEndTime` has an iterator into `burstTimeCopy`, so you don't need to use `burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID]`; just use `*it`.  Also, you should use `++it` to increment the iterator, which avoids creating an unused copy of the iterator (which may or may not be optimized out).

However the while loop can be rewritten to not need `burstTimeCopy` at all.  Keep track of the total elapsed time and use that, rather than reducing all your times towards zero.

`printInfo` can be a const member function.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using the same definition of the `Scheduling` class, which is declared in `Scheduling.h`, and defining it multiple times in different files. Here, you define it in `roundrobin.cpp`, but in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197269/priority-scheduling-algorithm-preemptive/), you define it in a completely different `.cpp` file. This is a very odd way to be organizing your code.

Here is how I would do it instead:

1. `Scheduling` is a strange name for an object. It should be a concrete noun like `Scheduler`. Your `Scheduler` class should be declared in a header file, `Scheduler.hpp`, and then defined in a separate file of the same name, `Scheduler.cpp`.
2. If you're implementing multiple schedulers that use the same interface, then these schedulers should inherit from a common base class. As such, you should make `Scheduler` an abstract base class and then have other schedulers inherit from them. They would have names like `RoundRobinScheduler`, for example. `RoundRobinScheduler` would be declared in a header file `RoundRobinScheduler.hpp` and then defined in a separate file, `RoundRobinScheduler.cpp`.

This more closely follows conventions and allows someone to be able to use more than one of your schedulers at the same time. It will also give you experience in designing derived classes that share a common interface, which is a necessary skill to have when doing object-oriented programming.

Comment: The member function in `Scheduling.h`, for eg. `calcEndTime()` will have different definition for different scheduling algorithm, so we cannot define it in `scheduling.cpp` and this is first time I am writing code involving inheritance and header, can you provide any link for reference.

Comment: Yes, it's quite common for functions in derived classes to have different definitions. You could make it pure virtual in the base class. The only functions you would define in the base class are those that are common to all the derived classes. Any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will have information on inheritance and abstract classes.