# Follow up: CPU Scheduling Algorithm (SJF, priority & Round Robin)

Tags: c++, c++11

After implementing suggestions from my previous questions about [SJF](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197076/shortest-job-first-preemptive/197177#197177), [priority](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197269/priority-scheduling-algorithm-preemptive/197325?noredirect=1#comment380390_197325) and [round robin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197498/round-robin-scheduling-algorithm/197554?noredirect=1#comment380947_197554).

Here I have `scheduling.h` which contains a struct `Data` and `virtual` member functions. Then I have derived class for each scheduling algorithm. Only `calcEndTime()` is defined for each scheduling algorithm. I have asked to enter priority in each algortihm because it must be in `Data` so it is bounded to `arrivalTime` and `burstTime`. This is first time I have written program related to inheritance. Suggest me improvements.

scheduling.h

```
#ifndef SCHEDULING_H_
#define SCHEDULING_H_

#include <vector>

class Scheduler
{
  public:

    double avgWaitingTime;
    double avgTurnAroundTime;

    struct Data
    {
        unsigned arrivalTime;
        //When process start to execute
        unsigned burstTime;
        //only for priority Scheduling
        unsigned priority;

        Data(unsigned arrivalTime, unsigned burstTime, unsigned priority):
            arrivalTime(std::move(arrivalTime)),
            burstTime(std::move(burstTime)),
            priority(std::move(priority))
            {}
        Data() = default;
    };

    std::vector<Data> data;
    //process wait to execute after they have arrived
    std::vector<unsigned> waitingTime;
    //total time taken by processes
    std::vector<unsigned> turnAroundTime;
    //time when a process end
    std::vector<unsigned> endTime;

    Scheduler(unsigned num = 0);
    Scheduler(const Scheduler&)            = delete;
    Scheduler &operator=(const Scheduler&) = delete;
    Scheduler(Scheduler&&)                 = delete;
    Scheduler &operator=(Scheduler&&)      = delete;
    ~Scheduler()                           = default;

    void calcWaitingTime();
    void calcTurnAroundTime();
    virtual void calcEndTime() = 0;
    void printInfo() const;
};

#endif
```

scheduling.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "scheduling.h"

Scheduler::Scheduler(unsigned num): endTime(num, 0)
{
    unsigned arrivalVal, burstVal, priorityVal;
    data.reserve(num);
    endTime.reserve(num);
    waitingTime.reserve(num);
    turnAroundTime.reserve(num);

    std::cout << "\nEnter arrival time and burst time and priority eg(5 18 2)\n";
    std::cout << "If it is not priority scheduling enter 0 for priority\n";
    std::cout << "Lower integer has higher priority\n";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nProcess" << i+1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> arrivalVal >> burstVal >> priorityVal;
        data.push_back( Data(arrivalVal, burstVal, priorityVal) );
    }
}

void Scheduler::calcTurnAroundTime()
{
    double sum = 0.00;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned val = endTime[i] - data[i].arrivalTime;
        turnAroundTime.push_back(val);
        sum += (double)val;
    }
    avgTurnAroundTime = sum / turnAroundTime.size();
}

void Scheduler::calcWaitingTime()
{
    double sum = 0.00;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned val = turnAroundTime[i] - data[i].burstTime;
        waitingTime.push_back(val);
        sum += (double)val;
    }
    avgWaitingTime = sum / waitingTime.size();
}

void Scheduler::printInfo() const
{
    std::cout << "ProcessID\tArrival Time\tBurst Time\tPriority\tEnd Time\tWaiting Time";
    std::cout << "\tTurnaround Time\n";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i+1 << "\t\t" << data[i].arrivalTime << "\t\t";
        std::cout << data[i].burstTime << "\t\t" <<data[i].priority << "\t\t";
        std::cout << endTime[i] << "\t\t";
        std::cout << waitingTime[i] <<"\t\t" << turnAroundTime[i] <<'\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Average Waiting Time : " << avgWaitingTime << '\n';
    std::cout << "Average Turn Around Time : " << avgTurnAroundTime << '\n';
}
```

shortestjobfirst.h

```
#ifndef SHORTESTJOBFIRST_H_
#define SHORTESTJOBFIRST_H_

#include "scheduling.h"

class ShortestJobFirst : public Scheduler
{
  public:
    ShortestJobFirst(unsigned num);
    ShortestJobFirst() = default;
    ShortestJobFirst(const ShortestJobFirst&)            = delete;
    ShortestJobFirst &operator=(const ShortestJobFirst&) = delete;
    ShortestJobFirst(ShortestJobFirst&&)                 = delete;
    ShortestJobFirst &operator=(ShortestJobFirst&&)      = delete;
    ~ShortestJobFirst()                                  = default;

    void calcEndTime();
};

#endif
```

shortestjobfirst.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits
#include "scheduling.h"
#include "shortestjobfirst.h"


ShortestJobFirst::ShortestJobFirst(unsigned num) :Scheduler(num)
                                                  {}

void ShortestJobFirst::calcEndTime()
{
    //If arrival time is not sorted
    //sort burst time according to arrival time
    static const auto byArrival = [](const Data &a, const Data &b)
    {
        return a.arrivalTime < b.arrivalTime;
    };
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), byArrival);

    //copy values of burst time in new vector
    std::vector<unsigned> burstTimeCopy;
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        unsigned val = (*it).burstTime;
        burstTimeCopy.push_back(val);
    }

    unsigned timeCounter = 0;
    unsigned currActiveProcessID = 0;
    while (!(std::all_of(burstTimeCopy.begin(), burstTimeCopy.end(),
          [] (unsigned e) { return e == 0; })))
    {
        std::size_t dataSize = data.size();
        //All processes are not arrived
        if (timeCounter <= data[dataSize -1].arrivalTime)
        {
            unsigned minBurstTime = std::numeric_limits<uint>::max();
            //Find index with minimum burst Time remaining
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < burstTimeCopy.size(); i++)
            {
                if (burstTimeCopy[i] != 0 && burstTimeCopy[i] < minBurstTime
                  && data[i].arrivalTime <= timeCounter)
                {
                    minBurstTime = burstTimeCopy[i];
                    currActiveProcessID = i;
                }
            }
            burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] -= 1;
            timeCounter++;
            if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] == 0)
            {
                endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
            }
        }
        else //When all processes are arrived
        {
            unsigned minBurstTime = std::numeric_limits<uint>::max();
            //Find index with minimum burst Time remaining
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < burstTimeCopy.size(); i++)
            {
                if (burstTimeCopy[i] != 0 && burstTimeCopy[i] < minBurstTime)
                {
                    minBurstTime = burstTimeCopy[i];
                    currActiveProcessID = i;
                }
            }
            timeCounter += minBurstTime;
            endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
            burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of processes\n";
    std::cin >> num;
    ShortestJobFirst batch(num);
    batch.calcEndTime();
    batch.calcTurnAroundTime();
    batch.calcWaitingTime();
    batch.printInfo();
}
```

`Priority`, `ShortestJobFirst` are nearly smae and in `RoundRobin` we have member function `timeQuantum` which is entered through constructor.

priorit.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits
#include "scheduling.h"
#include "priority.h"

Priority::Priority(unsigned num): Scheduler(num)
                                  {}

void Priority::calcEndTime()
{
    //If arrival time is not sorted
    //sort burst time according to arrival time
    static const auto byArrival = [](const Data &a, const Data &b)
    {
        return a.arrivalTime < b.arrivalTime;
    };
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), byArrival);

    //copy values of burst time in new vector
    std::vector<unsigned> burstTimeCopy;
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        unsigned val = (*it).burstTime;
        burstTimeCopy.push_back(val);
    }

    unsigned timeCounter = 0;
    unsigned currActiveProcessID = 0;
    while (!(std::all_of(burstTimeCopy.begin(), burstTimeCopy.end(),
            [] (unsigned e) { return e == 0; })))
    {
        std::size_t dataSize = data.size();
        //All processes are not arrived
        if (timeCounter <= data[dataSize - 1].arrivalTime)
        {
            unsigned maxPriority = std::numeric_limits<uint>::max();
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < burstTimeCopy.size(); i++)
            {
                if (burstTimeCopy[i] != 0 && data[i].priority < maxPriority
                    && data[i].arrivalTime <= timeCounter)
                {
                    maxPriority = data[i].priority;
                    currActiveProcessID = i;
                }
            }
            burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] -= 1;
            timeCounter++;
            if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] == 0)
            {
                endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
            }
        }
        else //When all processes are arrived
        {
            unsigned maxPriority = std::numeric_limits<uint>::max();
            for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < burstTimeCopy.size(); i++)
            {
                if (burstTimeCopy[i] != 0 && data[i].priority < maxPriority)
                {
                    maxPriority = data[i].priority;
                    currActiveProcessID = i;
                }
            }
            timeCounter += burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID];
            burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] = 0;
            endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of processes\n";
    std::cin >> num;
    Priority prioritySchedule(num);
    prioritySchedule.calcEndTime();
    prioritySchedule.calcTurnAroundTime();
    prioritySchedule.calcWaitingTime();
    prioritySchedule.printInfo();
}
```

roundrobin.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::find
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end
#include <limits> //std::numeric_limits
#include "scheduling.h"
#include "roundrobin.h"

RoundRobin::RoundRobin(unsigned num, unsigned quantum): Scheduler(num)
{
    timeQuantum = quantum;
}

void RoundRobin::calcEndTime()
{
    //If arrival time is not sorted
    //sort burst time according to arrival time
    static const auto byArrival = [](const Data &a, const Data &b)
    {
        return a.arrivalTime < b.arrivalTime;
    };
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), byArrival);

    //copy values of burst time in new vector
    std::vector<unsigned> burstTimeCopy;
    for (auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        unsigned val = (*it).burstTime;
        burstTimeCopy.push_back(val);
    }

    unsigned timeCounter = 0;
    while (!(std::all_of(burstTimeCopy.begin(), burstTimeCopy.end(),
            [] (unsigned e) { return e == 0; })))
    {
        unsigned currActiveProcessID = 0;
        auto it = burstTimeCopy.begin();
        while (it != burstTimeCopy.end())
        {
            if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] > timeQuantum)
            {
                burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] -= timeQuantum;
                timeCounter += timeQuantum;
            }
            else if (burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] > 0)
            {
                timeCounter += burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID];
                burstTimeCopy[currActiveProcessID] = 0;
                endTime[currActiveProcessID] = timeCounter;
            }
            currActiveProcessID++;
            it++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned num, timeQuantum;
    std::cout << "Enter number of process: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << "\nEnter time quantum : ";
    std::cin >> timeQuantum;
    RoundRobin roundRobin(num, timeQuantum);
    roundRobin.calcEndTime();
    roundRobin.calcTurnAroundTime();
    roundRobin.calcWaitingTime();
    roundRobin.printInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, in `Scheduler`, I would replace

```
std::vector<Data> data;
std::vector<unsigned> waitingTime;
std::vector<unsigned> turnAroundTime;
std::vector<unsigned> endTime;
```

by

```
struct Process {
    Data data;
    unsigned waitingTime, turnAroundTime, endTime;        
};
std::vector<Process> processes;
```

or put the members `waitingTime` `turnAroundTime` `endTime` in `Data` directly